# mail merge e-mail in Word 2007 with attachment

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, mail-merge

Is there a **simple** way to mail merge with Word 2007 and add an attachment? I've searched google, and all results point to pasting in VB code.

I want to a small team of novice users to be able to mail merge e-mails and add attachments.

Does anyone know a simple way of doing this without code?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. It seems MS recognizes this is something people would want to do, but they haven't made a non-VB method available. Microsoft says it can't be done just using the software. [link text](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA011464811033.aspx)

Here is a link to the macro method. Maybe the trick is to set up the macro and then make it easy for your people to run (e.g. placing it on the mail merge toolbar). [link text](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MailMerge/MergeWithAttachments.htm)

Of course, you can always consider add-ons as the other answer suggests. I personally have no experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

The [MAPILab mail merge toolkit](http://www.mapilab.com/outlook/mail_merge/) actually looks like a good product.  I suggest you stay away from rk_20_2's link - they're already up to version 2.5.6.  Don't pirate an old version; buy a copy - it's only $24.

(BTW, I'm not affiliated with them, never used the product, your mileage may vary, etc).